# Double speed playback in all music player apps on Acer Aspire One ZA3 running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-player

Whatever music player that I install plays music as if it were in x2 playback mode.

I have reinstalled and updated Alsa and PulseAudio and everything remains the same.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my laptop is an ACER ASPIRE ONE Model ZA3 which has 1GB of RAM. I am using the i686 version of Ubuntu. I have reinstalled my operating system several times and the problem continues.

Comment: If I can help someone with this same problem, after a long investigation I have managed to solve the mysterious problem. Here are the steps for your solution:
1- Open the Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)
2-Enter the command (pulseaudio -k)
And you will have audio with the best quality that exists, do not ask me why but the whole problem was Pulseaudio that does not load well.
Thank you and I hope it helps someone in the future